# calling a function in another file in javascript using node.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express

I have a problem, i am trying to create an object that i can use over and over in a separate javascript file. I have a file called foo.js and another file called boo.js. I want to create the object in boo.js In my server.js file i required foo.js, and it works fine i can access foo.js. I want to be able to access boo.js from foo.js. I keep getting errors when i require boo.js in foo.js and i cant access it. Is There a way to do this?

here is my code

```
//boo.js
var obj = function () {
   return {
     data: 'data'
  }
}

module.exports = {
  obj: obj
}
```

foo.js

```
//foo.js

var request = require('request');
var x = require('./modules/boo')
var random= function() {
    return x.obj();
}

module.exports = {
  random: random
}
```

Comment: What is the error you're getting "*when i require boo.js in foo.js*?" Where are the files located in relation to each other? Are they in the same or different directories?

Comment: i get the error cant find module boo, they are both in the same directory.

Comment: i changed my file path for boo from ./modules/boo to ./boo and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are in the same directory you will want to require like so `var x = require('./boo')`. The `./` is relative to the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

> they are both in the same directory

In that case, you'll want to remove the `modules/` from the path:

```
var x = require('./boo');
```

---

`require()` is aware of the current script's location and bases relative paths from the script's own parent directory.

The `./` at the start of the path will refer to the same directory as `__dirname`, which seems to be `modules/`.

```
console.log(__dirname);
// "/project-path/modules"
```

Including `modules/` in the path will result in doubling it:

```
var path = require('path');

console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, './modules/boo'));
// "/project-path/modules/modules/boo"
```

---

(Side note: The `fs` module does not behave the same way. Relative paths for it are based from the current working directory or `process.cwd()`.)